# Get Prometheus Datasources names in a Grafana Dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to monitor some group of servers with Grafana and Prometheus. For each group of servers, I have a Prometheus Database. It is a requirement to have an isolated Prometheus DB for each group of servers.

All the Prometheus DBs are successfully connected to the same Grafana server.

The issue is how to auto-repeat a singlestat panel for each DataSource. I can change the Datasource of a Panel with a Datasource variable. But I can't repeat this panel for all the Prometheus Datasources.

I tried to repeat a panel with the Datasources variable but it only works with one value. In other types of variables I can include the option "All" but that can not be applied for variables of type Datasource.

Is this posible?

Is posible to obtain a list of name of all the PrometheusDBs Datasources to use them on a Dashboard variable?

Thank you very much,

Alex